# How to get role of user asking command in Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to find out whether the user for a command (`whotohelp`) has certain roles('Lab Demonstrator`), however, I do not seem to understand how I can get the role.

For my on 'interactionCreate` I currently have the following:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {

  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
  (interaction.commandName);
  //gets username
  var username = (interaction.user.username);
  //test code
  if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
  
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
  }
```

In Python I used `@commands.has_any_role("Lab Demonstrator","lab demonstrator", "staff")` as in:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Lab Demonstrator","lab demonstrator", "staff","teaching-assistant","lecturers","admin", "Admin")
async def whoToHelp(mesage):
```

What would be the Javascript alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Collection.some` for a boolean and `Collection.find` for the role object.

**Boolean**

```js
const hasRole = interaction.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "the_role_name")
//true if they have it, false if they don't
```

**Role Object**

```js
const role = interaction.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "the_role_name")
//the role object if they have it
```

Comment: Thank you - I have spent way too long on this and you answer it in 4 minutes! cheers

Comment: If it helped, please mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark

Comment: Sure done - sorry for the delay, stack overflows wanted me to wait 15 minutes before I could mark it as answered